# Flutter - shift focus to specific widget

Tags: widget, flutter, focus, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter app targeting visually impaired users. In my app after the user search for information using editbox. The app lack notifying the user that the search completed.

I am willing to do that by shifting focus to search result so that the screen reader reads it (Talkback or VoiceOver). In Android for example I can use :

```
View.requestFocus();
```

I am looking for approach to perform the same thing in flutter or custom platform code

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to clear up some misconceptions. I've seen variations of Aawaz Gyawali's solution posted elsewhere. This doesn't work.

Flutter has two types of focus. The first is "Input Focus". This determines what form field currently has focus, and that's what FocusNode handles.

The second type of focus is "Accessibility Focus". This is the box presented by TalkBack / Voiceover. It's completely separate from "Input Focus". You can change the input focus all you want, but that accessibility focus will remain the same.

The fact that we can't change accessibility focus in Flutter is a massive oversight and a major roadblock to creating accessible apps.

**EDIT**
For the sake of completeness I did find an ugly workaround to this.

If you change the focus to a form field, such as a textfield, then the accessibility focus will update as well.

In my case I'm using a FlatButton which has pretty much no styling attached to it. Obviously you then have to make that button *do* something, but it at least gets you in the neighborhood of where you want to be.

Hacky? Absolutely, but in lieu of better options this is what I've got at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FocusNode` for this.
Check the sample code [here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/focus).

Comment: This was designed for TextEdit widget, I am looking for using this feature on Text widget